# Does IMU data improve odometry in Gazebo?

Tags: imu, gazebo, navigation, odometry, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Would using /robot_pose_ekf to fuse odometry and IMU data give me a better pose estimate in a Gazebo simulation? Or does Gazebo provide perfect odometry data without slip and drift?

Thanks!

-Alan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64410/does-imu-data-improve-odometry-in-gazebo?/) by [ajhamlet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4140/ajhamlet/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The question is a bit unclear.  Gazebo can give you a ground-truth pose with respect to the gazebo defined origin.  If you are defining your own origin and using a package to calculate the odometry, then depending on the noise the IMU data can improve or degrade the odometry calculations.

---

Originally posted by [astaranowicz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4294/astaranowicz/) with karma: 238 on 2013-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ajhamlet](https://answers.ros.org/users/4140/ajhamlet/) on 2013-06-06**:
Oh, I was unaware of that, so that actually answers my question! Cheers!